# Strange behaviour in Collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with 25 cells For one cell i have created text color as white. Now when i reload the collection view the other cells text color also changes to white color one by one when ever i reload collection view. I dont know where the problem lies. Here is my code.

```
        if (indexPath.item == 0)
    {
        myCell.hidden=NO;
        NSLog(@"index path = %ld",(long)indexPath.row );
        NSArray *Object=  [[jsonData valueForKey:@"TimeTabledPeriods"]objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"object %@",Object);
        myCell.roomLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Room: %@", [Object valueForKey:@"RoomDescription"]];
        myCell.subjectLabel.text =  [Object valueForKey:@"SubjectDescription"];
        [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet setTag:indexPath.row];
        [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        myCell.noSessionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        myCell.myLearningChoicesBackground.hidden=YES;

        if ([[Object valueForKey:@"Changed"] isEqualToString:@"YES"])
        {
            if ([[Object valueForKey:@"ChangedColorCode"] isEqualToString:@"Present"])
            {
                myCell.noSessionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:97.0/255.0 green:182.0/255.0 blue:73/255.0 alpha:1];

    //The below lines to change the text color to white is written only for index path  0
                myCell.roomLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
                myCell.subjectLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

            }

        }
//code for other cells

    if (indexPath.item == 1)
{
    myCell.hidden=NO;
    NSLog(@"index path = %ld",(long)indexPath.row );
    NSArray *Object=  [[jsonData valueForKey:@"TimeTabledPeriods"]objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"object %@",Object);
    myCell.roomLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Room: %@", [Object valueForKey:@"RoomDescription"]];
    myCell.subjectLabel.text =  [Object valueForKey:@"SubjectDescription"];
    [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet setTag:indexPath.row];
    [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    myCell.noSessionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    myCell.myLearningChoicesBackground.hidden=YES;

    if ([[Object valueForKey:@"Changed"] isEqualToString:@"YES"])
    {
        if ([[Object valueForKey:@"ChangedColorCode"] isEqualToString:@"Present"])
        {
            myCell.noSessionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:97.0/255.0 green:182.0/255.0 blue:73/255.0 alpha:1];

        }

    }

    if (indexPath.item == 3)
{
    myCell.hidden=NO;
    NSLog(@"index path = %ld",(long)indexPath.row );
    NSArray *Object=  [[jsonData valueForKey:@"TimeTabledPeriods"]objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"object %@",Object);
    myCell.roomLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Room: %@", [Object valueForKey:@"RoomDescription"]];
    myCell.subjectLabel.text =  [Object valueForKey:@"SubjectDescription"];
    [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet setTag:indexPath.row];
    [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    myCell.noSessionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    myCell.myLearningChoicesBackground.hidden=YES;

    if ([[Object valueForKey:@"Changed"] isEqualToString:@"YES"])
    {
        if ([[Object valueForKey:@"ChangedColorCode"] isEqualToString:@"Present"])
        {
            myCell.noSessionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:97.0/255.0 green:182.0/255.0 blue:73/255.0 alpha:1];

        }

    }
```

// and so on
}

Comment: Now this is tableView or collectionView

Comment: Can you add code for other cells?

Comment: sorry i had typed it wrong its a collection view

Comment: yes i have edited @hoya21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing "strange" about this behavior, it's the result of not dealing properly with cell reuse. You set the text to white inside that first if clause, but never set it back to any other color in the other if clauses. So, when that cell is reused, it's text will still be set to white. It also appears that the code, other than that color change is the same inside each of your if clauses, so you shouldn't even have all those if clauses for each item; you need to refactor your code to eliminate all that duplication. Outside of any if clauses, if you actually still need any of them, you should set the text color to white for only item 0, and to black for all others,

```
myCell.roomLabel.textColor = (indexPath.item == 0)? [UIColor whiteColor] : [UIColor blackColor];
myCell.subjectLabel.textColor= (indexPath.item == 0)? [UIColor whiteColor] : [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want the first item and not the first row.

```
if (indexPath.item == 0)
{
    myCell.hidden=NO;
    NSLog(@"index path = %ld",(long)indexPath.row );
    NSArray *Object=  [[jsonData valueForKey:@"TimeTabledPeriods"]objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"object %@",Object);
    myCell.roomLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Room: %@", [Object valueForKey:@"RoomDescription"]];
    myCell.subjectLabel.text =  [Object valueForKey:@"SubjectDescription"];
    [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet setTag:indexPath.row];
    [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    myCell.noSessionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    myCell.myLearningChoicesBackground.hidden=YES;

    if ([[Object valueForKey:@"Changed"] isEqualToString:@"YES"])
    {
        if ([[Object valueForKey:@"ChangedColorCode"] isEqualToString:@"Present"])
        {
            myCell.noSessionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:97.0/255.0 green:182.0/255.0 blue:73/255.0 alpha:1];

//The below lines to change the text color to white is written only for index path  0
            myCell.roomLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            myCell.subjectLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

        }

    }
```

**EDIT**

Here it is how i handle collection view cells.

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];

UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];


UIStoryboard *storyboard=[[UIStoryboard alloc] init];



currentIndexPath=indexPath;

int selectedCellNum=(int)indexPath.item;

if (selectedCellNum==0) {

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {


        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];

    }



    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1B copy.png"];

    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    POISTableViewController * destViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"POISList"];



    destViewController.selectedCategory=0;

    destViewController.sightsToShow=self.groups;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destViewController animated:YES];







}
else if (selectedCellNum==1)
{

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {


        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];

    }



    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2B copy.png"];

    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    MonumentsViewController * destViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MonumentsViewController"];

    destViewController.sightsToShow=self.groups;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destViewController animated:YES];




}
```

Comment: no change... it behaves as same as it was previously

Comment: try to change if to else if.Maybe it works.Or make some debug with indexPath value and if it gets in wrong condition code.

Comment: same as what i have done... i think its becoz of too many lines and cells